# gradlew install package R does not exist

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Im trying to build a maven library, basically i created a new project and wrapped the relevant files as a module, but when im trying to call the command

```
 gradlew install
```

i keep getting this error: 
[image]

seems like there are some errors creating a javadoc for some reason, i've triple checked the doc and removed any special attributes from it, its literally just a plain text at this point so i have reason to believe its something to do with the other errors i see in the output saying package R does not exist.

I'm using Java 1.8 based on the guide in this page :http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

i have no idea what im doing wrong here. this whole process is somewhat random.

here is my module's gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = 'designtoolbox-styleable-dialog'

publishedGroupId = 'com.lirancohen.designtoolbox'
libraryName = 'designtoolbox-styleable-dialog'
artifact = 'designtoolbox-styleable-dialog'

libraryDescription = 'A fully customize-able dialog for android'

siteUrl = 'https://cohen_liran@bitbucket.org/cohen_liran/design-toolbox'
gitUrl = 'https://cohen_liran@bitbucket.org/cohen_liran/design-toolbox.git'

libraryVersion = '0.0.1'

developerId = 'lirancr'
developerName = '[MY NAME]'
developerEmail = '[MY EMAIL]'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

After trying for hours to resolve this myself i thought i will pop this up here, i will also update if i end up sorting this on my own

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question, in the end i went with removing the final references which throw the errors, i think its something to do with the R package should remain dynamic so it cant be declared final in external libs